# Updating and deleting contact immediately fails with 412 precondition failed

Tags: c#, gdata, google-contacts-api

I did the following:
1) updated an existing google contact
2) got the updated contact(with the new etag) as the return value of the api call
3) issued a delete request on that updated contact

And I got a 412 precondition failed although the etag in the request and the response matched as I found out in fiddler.

I debugged my code, and going through the code step-by-step worked out fine with no errors at all. So I guess it's a sync/timing issue.

As far as I know, the gdata lib for C# offers no support for this kind of issue. Is it a bug(didn't find anything on this online)? How should I tackle this?

Comment: Yep it's a bug. Or a feature. Depends on how you see it.

Comment: It's best to work around the issue, by trying to avoid back-to-back operations against the same resource.